# Create new SF opportunity from within an iFrame

Tags: apex, lightning, opportunity, iframe, create-records

I currently have an iFrame which is loaded into SF using syntax similar to below.

```
<apex:component>
<apex:iframe src="SomeURL"
 scrolling="true"
 height="600"
 width="1000"/>
</apex:component>
```

The iFrame contains a self hosted web app which does have some data taken from salesforce. I do have access to some data points for things like the **"Contact" [ID,NAME,ETC]** etc with in my iFrame.

Is it possible to open a **"New Opportunity"** for an existing client from within the iFrame?

What are my options for creating a new opportunity by pressing a button in the iFrame. Could it even be to simply open a new window (if possible) using some generic URL plus the company ID field data like the below example for opening a contact.

```
https://eu9.lightning.force.com/one/one.app#/sObject/<%= company.id %>/view
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [apex:canvasApp](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_app_vf_component_ref.htm) component to pass a session Id to your hosted website. From there, you can call the REST or SOAP API, direct the user to a Salesforce page, and so on. The specifics will depend on the technology you're using in your canvas app. For more details, read about the [Canvas Framework](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/canvas_framework.pdf).

Comment: I don't want to put SF in an iFrame, I have a self made web app which is already embeded in an iFrame already in SF and I to have a button in my iFrame to create a "new opportunity" in SF when you click it.

Comment: @Fasani Edited to reflect my newer understanding of your question.